# Rest API data reading present in swagger url using python library

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to access swagger url that gives response upon sending request in json format. I have disabled to avoid SSLCertVerificationError using verify=False. How to access that please help me to read it using python code. You can get details what I have tried till now.

1. Installed requests library by using cmd in windows = pip install requests
2. I am able to get the 200 response by using code mentioned
3. When I am trying to use "params= payload" where. I am not able to get the response the same I am getting in the swagger url.

url : https:///#!/prepaid-estimate-controller/getAccountDetailsUsingPOST

payload={'searchCriteria': 'string',  'value': 'string'}

```html
r4 = requests.get('https://<domain>/#!/prepaid-estimate-controller/getAccountDetailsUsingPOST', verify=False)
print(r4)

Output : 200

payload={'searchCriteria': 'string',  'value': 'string'}
r4 = requests.get('https://<domain>/#!/prepaid-estimate-controller/getAccountDetailsUsingPOST',params=payload, verify=False)
print(r4)
print(r4.text)

Output: DOM structure returns
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by using below code generated in the postman.

```
import requests
```

url = "https:///bsi/prepaid/getAccountDetails"

payload = "{  \r\n "searchCriteria": "BAID",  \r\n "value": "PPB006788"\r\n}"
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, verify=False)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))